# Binary search implementation in C

Tags: algorithm, c

```
int bin_search(int* a, int key)
{
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int) - 1;

   while(lo <=hi)
   {
        int mid = (lo + hi)/2;

        if(key < a[mid]) { hi = mid - 1;}
        else if (key > a[mid]) { lo = mid + 1;}
        else                    return mid;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

....

```
for(i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
{
    printf("%d\n", bin_search(a, i));
}
```

I think that I have a problem with this, but I can't understand why:

```
int hi = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int) - 1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof(a)` in this case is `sizeof(int*)` which is 4 or 8 on most machines. The most simple solution would be passing the length of the input array. Otherwise, your code looks nifty.

Answer (score 3):

1. As [@coderodde](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105355/29485) answered, `int hi = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int) - 1;` is certainly wrong. Size of `a` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the array. Suggest

   ```
   int bin_search(int* a, int number_elements, int key) {
     int lo = 0;
     int hi = number_elements - 1;
   ```
2. As the array is not changed, make it `const`.

   ```
   int bin_search(const int* a, ...
   ```
3. Guard against `int` overflow.  Below is a simple guard

   ```
   // int mid = (lo + hi)/2;
   int mid = (lo*1LL + hi)/2;
   ```
4. In general, I prefer to use `size_t number_element` rather than `int` as `size_t` is the right type to use as an array index.  `int` may be insufficient. But then the failure mechanism of `-1` needs re-thinking as `size_t` is some unsigned type.  Perhaps:

   ```
   // Return T/F on if value was found.  Save index in *result.
   bool bin_search(int* a, size_t number_elements, int key, size_t *result) {
   ```

`size_t` is more robust, but problems can occur with `mid - 1`

```
bool bin_search(const int* a, size_t size, int key, size_t *index) {
  size_t lo = 0;
  size_t hip1 = size;  // hi plus 1

  while(lo < hip1) {
    size_t mid = (lo*1LLU + hip1 -1)/2;

    if (key < a[mid]) { hip1 = mid;}
    else if (key > a[mid]) { lo = mid + 1;}
    else {
      *index = mid;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what's been said, if you wanted to implement a completely correct binary search you would have to watch for overflow when you add `hi` and `low`.

```
int mid = low + (hi - low) / 2;
```

Gives you back the value of the mid if your values of high and low are close to the maximum value if the data type you're using to store the number.

Comment: In general, `(hi - low)` may overflow given any 2 `int` values, but here we know `0<=low<=hi` and overflow not possible. Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is sensible, I have minor formatting suggestions:

```
(lo <=hi)
```

Should have simmetrical space, like:

```
(lo <= hi)
```

And

```
    if(key < a[mid]) { hi = mid - 1;}
    else if (key > a[mid]) { lo = mid + 1;}
    else                    return mid;
```

Should use multiple lines, like:

```
    if(key < a[mid]) {
         hi = mid - 1;
    } else if (key > a[mid]) {
         lo = mid + 1;
    } else {
         return mid;
    }
```

As people are more used to this format  and will read it at a glance.

Comment: Small typo: `i = mid - 1` should be `hi = mid - 1`